# How to unit test for WPF View Files example SomeView.Xaml

Tags: xaml, testing

How to Unit Test the WPF View Files like Sample.xaml and sample.xaml.cs files in mvvm pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WPF you don't need to unit test the xaml. Xaml are just UI that are bound to the view model. What you really need to test is the view model after all, the state of the application should be in the view model not in the xaml.

Let's say for example you want to test if a button is visible after a certain logic. What you need to do is to create a property in the viewmodel (i.e. IsButtonShown) which is a boolean and bind it to the visibility of the button that has a boolean to visibility converter.

```
<Button Content="Click Me!" Visibility="{Binding IsButtonShown, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" />
```

Through binding you can now see the state of every property of the UI from the viewmodel so that you don't need to create a unit test for the xaml.

Now in your unit test, you can do something like:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
       viewModel.InsideThisMethodWeSetIsButtonShownToFalse();
       Assert.IsTrue(!viewModel.IsButtonShown);
    }
```

Comment: So how do you do test-driven if you don't unit test the View? At some point, code will need to go into either the xaml or the code behind. Where is the test to drive that?

Comment: That's exactly the point, you can do test driven development by creating a unit test for the viewmodel without having to involve the view. The point where the xaml will be involved is during the binding. It will be bound to the properties of the viewmodel and changes in the xaml will reflect to the view model vice versa. That is of course when we set the correct binding.

Comment: I had completely forgotten I had even asked this question. 2 years on and having gained considerable experience with MVVM, I now totally get how unit-testing the ViewModel _is_ essentially testing the View, provided of course that the View is completely declarative and free of business logic...but then that should be the case if following MVVM as prescribed.